# Apache error "Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name"

Tags: server, apache2

When I restart my Apache server using the command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

I get the following error:

```
Restarting web server apache2
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
... waiting apache2:
Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
```

Is the server using 127.0.1.1 instead of 127.0.0.1? What causes this error?

Answer (score 619, accepted):

## 13.04 and older

This is just a friendly warning and not really a problem (as in that something does not work).

If you go to:

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

and insert:

```
ServerName localhost
```

and then restart apache by typing into the terminal:

```
sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

the notice will disappear.

If you have a name inside `/etc/hostname` you can also use that name instead of `localhost`.

---

And it uses `127.0.1.1` if it is inside your `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 myhostname
```

**[Preferred method](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP#Troubleshooting_Apache)**

> Troubleshooting Apache

If you get this error:

```
apache2: Could not determine the server's fully qualified domain name, 
using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
```

then use a text editor such as "sudo nano" at the command line or "gksudo gedit" on the desktop to create a new file,

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/conf.d/fqdn
```

or

```
gksu "gedit /etc/apache2/conf.d/fqdn"
```

then add

```
ServerName localhost
```

to the file and save. This can all be done in a single command with the following:

```
 echo "ServerName localhost" | sudo tee /etc/apache2/conf.d/fqdn
```

But on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
 echo "ServerName localhost" | sudo tee /etc/apache2/conf-available/fqdn.conf
 sudo a2enconf fqdn
```

Don't forget the ".conf" (without will not work).

Comment: This is also mentioned in the Ubuntu LAMP setup documentation for [Troubleshooting Apache](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP#Troubleshooting_Apache). There they recommend creating a file /etc/apache2/conf.d/fqdn with `ServerName localhost` in it

Comment: Very good answer - but I would also recommend putting it in the conf.d directory :)

Comment: `/etc/apache2/conf.d/` does not exist after my install of `lamp-server^` in 14.04

Comment: @redanimalwar For 13.10 and newer see [@Starx's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/396048/8698) below.

Comment: For the very last step (creating sym-link in 14.04) I'd recommend `sudo a2enconf fqdn` though it should technically be the same.

Comment: @Rinzwind you explained how to fix the issue, but why is it occurring?

Comment: @JohnMerlino why? because it is part of setting apache up?!

Comment: Why not configure the server FQDN in /etc/hosts ?

Comment: @HorusKol because it is no longer the preferred method. I would have added it in later but areeda already covered that method (and I would be stealing her answer).

Comment: @Rinzwind Why is it not the preferred method? Wouldn't it be better to set this at a server configuration level rather than at the apache service configuration?

Comment: @Rinzwind i did this works to remove that warning, but after restart apache i see `fail` in terminal log. and i restart my system but nothing changed and again after restarting apache `service apache2 restart` , i see `fail` !

Comment: i did get a 'cant bind to 0.0.0.0:80' error after trying this,,, but after i did a sudo killall apache2, then sudo service restart apache2,  this worked. Thanks!

Comment: The first part (adding the information on the apache2.conf) worked for me in the Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: ubuntu 10.04 + apache 2.2 do not have the fqdn file. How to solve this?

Comment: Upgrade your system since 10.04 is no longer an accepted Ubuntu. But .... I would assume the 1st part of the answer should work op Apache 2.2(?)

Comment: Re "*And it uses 127.0.1.1 if it is inside your /etc/hosts*"; Is this only for ubuntu? Or are there other OS that do this too?

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04 I edited existing file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf to add `ServerName localhost` and then did `sudo service apache2 restart` and it worked - no more warning. Before doing that, editing `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` had no effect (I confirmed by removing the file in the line after adding it to apache2.conf and restarting the server)

Comment: I confirmed the "But on Ubuntu 14.04" also worked on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, none of the others worked.  Warning went away.

Comment: To emphasise - if you're on a remote server that has some default host, it will be something like `ServerName example.com`

Answer (score 197):

## 13.10 or newer

As of Apache 2.4 - which is available by default as of 13.10 - you cannot use the method about adding a config file in the `conf.d` directory.

Apache no longer uses the `conf.d` directory. All the configuration files are stored inside `/etc/apache2/conf-available` directory and all the configuration files should now have a `.conf` extension.

In order to solve this message in Apache 2.4, we have to create a configuration file inside the conf-available directory. For example `servername.conf`.

```
sudo vi /etc/apache2/conf-available/servername.conf
```

And inside this we just need to add one line

```
ServerName localhost
```

You can combine the previous two commands in one with:

```
echo "ServerName localhost" | sudo tee /etc/apache2/conf-available/servername.conf
```

If you want to use a domain name or any other name depending on the requirement its fine, just replace `localhost` with whatever you need. Next you have to enable this configuration. For this, you need to run the following command:

```
sudo a2enconf servername
```

`a2enconf` is a command to enable a configuration file in Apaches 2.4. Also note that `servername` on the above command is from the name of the configuration file `servername.conf`. If your configuration file was `ngenericserver.conf` then you would have to write `sudo a2enconf ngenericserver`.

After this reload the server and the above message will no longer bug you.

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

or

```
sudo apache2ctl graceful
```

Now after this you will see that the message will not be shown again and the problem will be fixed.

Comment: Does anybody know how to make Apache say *which* config file it's having the problem with? I don't know why developers never think to put this in their error messages - it hardly takes much code!

Comment: If I have an Internet fqdm for this server, is this the place to put it? ie should I substitude myhost.org in place of localhost?

Comment: @CPBL This will be the default server name for all sites. If you only have one site, then that's all you need to do. If you have multiple sites on your server, you will also need to add the servername directive for each site in their respective virtual host configuration.

Comment: Works on 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Your quoted link seems dead, please fix.

Comment: This helped me, Thanks!

Comment: where are the a2* scripts such as a2enconf when building from source?

Comment: I found [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/install.html#customize) if you are building from source you have to edit the `PREFIX/conf/httpd.conf` where PREFIX is where you installed it and edit the [servername](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#servername) variable

Answer (score 37):

Apache2 can also get the FQDN from a properly configured system hostname rather than hardcoded into the apache config file. Hardcoding it will also cause confusion if the hostname changes. You actually don't need any `ServerName` directives in `httpd.conf` or any apache config files.

Put the following in `/etc/hosts`:

```
# IPv4 and IPv6 localhost aliases
127.0.0.1 hostname.domainname.com  hostname  localhost
::1       hostname.domainname.com  hostname  localhost
```

where `hostname.domainname.com` is the FQDN of your machine.

Along with a properly configured hostname in `/etc/hostname/` or with `hostnamectl`, this will also help other services on your machine run properly (i.e. the login prompt, showing `This is hostname.domainname.com` instead of `This is hostname.unknown_domain`.)

Comment: +1 for "a properly configured system hostname".  I wanted to configure the server properly.  This also fixed my error in the log `[warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) <fqdn> does NOT match server name!?`

Comment: Do you think this should work with Apache 2.2.22? I am still getting "Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName"

Comment: Is `hostname localhost` supposed to be `myubuntuservername localhost`? Or the string literal `hostname localhost`? You weren't clear in your answer

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  Seems that you may need to associate the FQDN to the static IP address rather than `127.0.0.1`, though.

Comment: This was the best answer for me on Ubuntu 18.04
I wish documentation was consistent though fully qualified domain name is not the same terminology here or anywhere. if my fully qualified domain name was google.com and my servername was google, my entry in /etc/hosts would be 127.0.0.1 google.com google I could replace the localhost line and ad local host to the end of this line if I wish.
I used this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 32):

- Open a terminal
- Open the `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` file:

  ```
  sudo editor /etc/apache2/httpd.conf # [1]
  ```
- By default, it would be blank. Simply add the following line:

  ```
  ServerName localhost
  ```
- Save the file and exit
- Restart the server

  ```
  sudo service apache2 restart
  ```

---

[1] Launch default editor, see `sudo update-alternatives --config editor`

Comment: after executing last command the following error occur

 ** Restarting web server apache2                                                /usr/sbin/apache2ctl: 87: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)

/usr/sbin/apache2ctl: 87: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
                                                                         [fail] ** @green7

Comment: try 'sudo service apache2 restart'

Answer (score 27):

In new version of apache2 you just following command like this:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Add the following new line end of file:

```
ServerName localhost
```

Then restart apache2:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

It's done.

Answer (score 7):

I find it is a bit better to create a new file in `/etc/conf.d` that to modify either `apache2.conf` or `httpd.conf`.

It's a personal preference that keeps my configuration changes separated from the distribution package.  So updates are less complicated.

I create the file `/etc/apache2/conf.d/AAserverName` and it contains only:

```
ServerName myhost.mycomain.tld
```

The other suggestions certainly work also.

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo -i

echo 'ServerName localhost' > /etc/apache2/conf-available/server-name.conf
a2enconf server-name
```

Answer (score 2):

On **Ubuntu 16.04**:

Add `ServerName localhost` to the file `httpd.conf` usin gthe following command.

```
sudo vi  /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Then include this line `Include httpd.conf` at the end of this file

```
sudo vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Check for syntax errors again

```
sudo apache2ctl configtest
```

You should now get

```
Syntax OK
```

You can now restart the server gracefully by reloading the configuration

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

or kill the process and start again

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `ServerName localhost`

To

```
 sudo leafpad /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

 sudo leafpad /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

It's not an error.. It's just a friend reminder

Answer (score 1):

Specifying `ServerName localhost` in your configuration files outside of the virtual host sections is the way to do this.

Some other answers suggest that you should modify `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`.  This file gets overwritten when apache gets upgraded from apt.  For Apache configuration that you don't want to get overwritten, you should create a new file.  Here is the "Debian way" to make this configuration change:

```
# create the configuration file in the "available" section
echo "ServerName localhost" | sudo tee /etc/apache2/conf-available/servername.conf
# enable it by creating a symlink to it from the "enabled" section
sudo a2enconf servername
# restart the server
sudo service apache2 restart
```

This is basically the same as Stark's answer, but in an easy to copy and paste script form.  I had originally posted this in a question that was marked as duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/a/432408

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 11.10, I saw this message, along with a hung boot occurring because my disk was full.  [One of the log files had gone rogue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/884239/comments/3).  Probably there was not actually a problem with Apache, but this message was the last clue given before the boot hung.

To fix the problem, I had to boot into recovery mode and remove the wayward log file.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command:

```
apachectl -t -D DUMP_INCLUDES
```

to determine path to your `httpd.conf` configuration file, then edit that file and uncomment/modify the line which specifies the value for `ServerName` option, e.g.

```
ServerName localhost
```

For the web server, use the registered DNS name (e.g. `example.com`).

> If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bash and want minimal dependencies (and just want a one-liner for your [entrypoint script if you are using Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#entrypoint) like me), these two options should work.

If you want localhost:

`echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

If you want the existing hostname:

`echo "ServerName $(cat /etc/hostname)" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

This uses the [bash redirection operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Appending-Redirected-Output) to append the string to the end of the file. Echo automatically inserts the newline, so you are all set.

Answer (score 0):

On **Ubuntu 16.04**:

Add `ServerName localhost` to the file `httpd.conf` usin gthe following command.

```
sudo vi  /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Then include this line `Include httpd.conf` at the end of this file

```
sudo vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Check for syntax errors again

```
sudo apache2ctl configtest
```

You should now get

```
Syntax OK
```

You can now restart the server gracefully by reloading the configuration 
sudo service apache2 restart