# Errors when trying to restart Apache

Tags: apache2

When trying to restart Apache (with: `service apache2 restart`), I get the following error:

```
/usr/sbin/apache2ctl: 87: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
/usr/sbin/apache2ctl: 87: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

When I try to restart it with another command (`sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`), I get the following error:

```
* Restarting web server apache2                                      
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified
domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName  ... waiting apache2:
Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name,
using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
```

I had previously edited `etc/apache2/httpd.conf` with:

```
ServerName localhost
```

In order to resolve the above issue, but it seems not to have worked.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: 1. it should be `sudo service apache2 restart`, 2. `The Apache error log may have more information.`, 3 `apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified` is not a problem but a configuration issue (and has been answered before: http://askubuntu.com/questions/256013/could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name?rq=1 ) after this apache still is started.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've been on that thread and have edited the httpd.conf accordingly but I still get the error - that's why I thought it would be a different problem to the one on that thread. How do I access the error log to see what's going on?

Comment: command line: see `/var/log` It will have an apache  log there.

Comment: @babbaggeii were you trying all of this on `docker` by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to get laughed off the planet. I was getting this error also; I had forgotten the all important sudo 
`sudo service apache2 restart`