# Apache2 giving SSLcertificateFile error

Tags: installation, apache2, ssl, certificates

I am using ubuntu 13.04.
Initially I had installed apache2 and it was working fine but later it started giving some issues so i removed apache using following commands

> sudo apt-get autoremove
>
> sudo apt-get remove apache2*
>
> dpkg -S `which apache2`

and then i reinstalled apache2 using

> sudo apt-get install apache2

Installation was almost done but then i got following message

> - Starting web server apache2
>     Syntax error on line 6 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ssl:
>     SSLCertificateFile: file '/etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem' does not exist or is empty
>     Action 'start' failed.
>     The Apache error log may have more information.
>
>   [fail]
>
>   invoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "start" failed.
>     Setting up apache2 (2.2.22-6ubuntu5.1) ...

```
output to ls /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ is default-ssl mysite ssl
```

content of mysite is

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

```
DocumentRoot /home/gautam/apache/
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /home/gautam/apache/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

after running sudo rm /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*ssl i am getting the following output and apache2 is OFF

```
* Restarting web server apache2                                                
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443
                                                                         [ OK ]
```

What to do? Any suggestions???

Comment: `ls  /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`? add output to question

Comment: output to ls /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ is default-ssl  mysite  ssl

Comment: Remove ssl sites if you don't need https server: `sudo rm /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*ssl` then `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: ya it started but now if i run http://localhost/ it doesn't display the default page

Comment: Could add contents of `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite` to your question?

Comment: I think it ie:`mysite` should be some thing like `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` with `<VirtualHost *:80></VirtualHost>` tags

Answer (score 1):

I had removed SSL but it was still giving following error:

> Restarting web server apache2 apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully
>   qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName apache2: Could not reliably
>   determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName 
>   (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443 [ OK ]

I googled it out and referred to these 2 posts:

- [Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256013/could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name/256018#256018)
- [“make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443” when restarting apache (installing trac and mod_wsgi)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143964/make-sock-could-not-bind-to-address-443-when-restarting-apache-installi)

Finally, I disabled the SSL using:

```
a2dismod ssl
```