# apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName ... waiting apache2:

Tags: server, apache2, xserver

I upgraded to ubuntu 14.04 yesterday. But after restarting PC , this message continues to appear in a black screen after the ubuntu loading screen and don't go away and ubuntu doesn't start I can do nothing about this. what should I do? I tried logging in from other terminals and do asm [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256013/could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name) but still nothing

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/256013/could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This can be overcome by two way.

1. Add `ServerName localhost` as the last line in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file.
2. Create a file named `/etc/apache2/conf-available/servername.conf` and add the string `ServerName localhost` inside and save it. Create a soft link under `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled` as follows

   ```
   ln -s /etc/apache2/conf-available/servername.conf .
   # or
   a2enconf servername
   ```

and restart the server.

The string `localhost` can be replaced with any valid domain name (ie. example.com).

Comment: I have removed apache via other tty. I couldn't log in to it.

Answer (score 4):

Another way of performing the second option suggested by ccsen is the following:

1. Create a file in /etc/apache2/conf-available/ with any desired name. servername.conf is a suitable option.
2. Add the following line to the created file: `ServerName yourservername`. yourservername can be set to anything you want.
3. Then run the following from a terminal: `sudo a2enconf servername` (assuming you called the file added to conf-available on step 1 'servername.conf').
4. Finally, run the following from the terminal: `sudo service apache2 reload`

Although both methods achieve the same result, I believe this one is cleaner since apache takes care of the symlinks and enabling the configuration.

Answer (score 4):

A third way is to configure your computer's hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       servername.domain.com       servername
```