# When accessing localhost I get a file browser rather than the "It works!"

Tags: webserver, localhost

I'm trying to deploy a set of html and php scripts which I've developed on another server, onto my laptop. I think I am pretty much at a default configuration setup, having never dealt with the `/var/www` on this machine.

I've run the `LAMP` install as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP) and restarted everything, but this didn't help

If I try to go to `localhost`, this is what I get:
[image: localhost]

Ownerships and groups are all set to `www-data` and readable. I am sure that this is something simple that I'm forgetting...

Thanks

EDIT: I'm also getting this error if I try to restart apache2. Shouldn't be an issue [though](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256013/could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name):

```
$ sudo /usr/sbin/apache2ctl restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using ::1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

Comment: check your httpd.conf or apache2.conf file in /etc/apache2 your document root seems to be overwritten

Comment: I'm looking at the file, but I don't know if it's wrong or not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed it! I have no idea why or how, but in sites-enabled/000-default.conf, DocumentRoot was set to /var/www/html. I removed the /html and now everything is fine.

For reference, this is how it's set to work:

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? The instructions linked in your first post were for 10.04, which used a different DocumentRoot compared to the latest release.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. I'm running 14.04 but maybe it's not been updated somehow.