# Problems starting Ubuntu Server 14.04.2

Tags: server, apache2

Yesterday, after some problems, finally I could install Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 and gnome GUI. Then I close the server.
This morning, when I open it again it stops in this line:
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message.

I've been looking for in Google, there are a lot of solutions, but no one works for me. Sure, because I'm new and there are a lot of things I don't know, but can somebody tell me how can I fix this problem? Please, step by step, I've tried to restart using recovery mode - root, but all commands fails.

Comment: That is not an error though. Check out this answer: [Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/256013/could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name/396048#396048)

Answer (score 1):

You can manually edit file  /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf (I am supposing you have a strictly default Apache configuration on your server).

You then change the line

```
    #ServerName www.example.com
```

and put in whatever IP address you use to connect from your clients, probably the server's IP address on eth0:

```
    ServerName 192.168.0.100
```

If you have a local DNS service up, you could also use your server's name, such as:

```
    ServerName www.localserver.local
```

In this case, both the clients and also the server will need to resolve this name.

Once this is written to the file, restart the Apache service (or reboot the computer) and the annoying message should go away for good.

HTH

Comment: thanks for your answer. I understand I have to change some configuration file, the problem is that I can't edit anything. I restart server in recovery mode, then I select root to access to the console. There I try to edit some thing (sudo gedit ...) and it says gedit command not found.
I don't know if I'm restarting bad, or what else to do. Thanks again

Comment: gedit is a graphical command, so won't work in a text environment. Try either vi or editor in the console. You may find the latter to be easier to use, and it is standard in ubuntu.