# How do I set the servername?

Tags: server, hostname

when i go to my digital ocean and type in the console to restart apache2, it tells me there is an error and i need to set the "servername directive globally"
I have seen a thread on this but I have tried it all and it still will not restart.

Comment: What *did* you try?

Comment: I have used many things mostly changing the apache2.conf or sudo phrases to restart apache2. none of these have worked but I would like to see if you know of any other ways

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [Apache error "Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256013/could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name)

Except maybe instead of setting the ServerName to 'localhost' you want to set it to your server's actual (DNS) hostname, or the IP address depending on your DNS setup.