# Problem determining domain name on startup

Tags: boot, visual-artifacts

From yesterday onwards when Ubuntu starts my system shows following error message:

```
Starting redis-server: redis-server.
speech dispatcher disabled; edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
 * Starting vnStat daemon vnstatd                                             [ OK ]
saned disabled; edit /etc/default/saned
 * Starting web server apache2
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name,
using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
                                                                              [ OK ]
 * Checking battery state...                                                  [ OK ]
 * Starting TiMidity++ ALSA midi emulation...                                 [ OK ]
```

[image]

Sometimes Ubuntu loads properly. Even though it loads properly after some time it freezes and next time onwards the same black error screen appears. Each time this error occurs the boot screen color also changes and some horizontal lines appear on the screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/256013/could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name)

Comment: What's the next line after the Starting Timidity ... emulation? Try to watch out for that next line. That's where the trouble comes from. I had problems with Timidity before, it's like very old software and sometimes conflicts with ALSA or with PulseAudio. Timidity was mainly used as the only viable tool for playing and editing MIDI audio files. MIDI files were used by old 2G phones as ringtones. Very clear sounds on 8-bit compression. Nobody uses that anymore, we got mp3s on every smartphone now.