# Problems openning Apache2

Tags: apache2

I've use the code `sudo apt-get install apache2`. 
After that I've tried to open it and it gave me this

```
[Thu Jan 26 11:39:14.983776 2017] [core:warn] [pid 13237] AH00111:
Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
AH00526: Syntax error on line 74 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid Mutex directory in argument file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}
```

What can I do?

Comment: What's on line 74 of `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`?

Comment: What do you mean by open it? Do you mean "start it"? If so, what was the command you ran to start apache? You can't just run `apache2`.

Comment: I just wrote apache2

Comment: @bc2946088 I wrote what you said but it said acces denied

Comment: I also wrote `apache2` and got the same error. To run Apache2 use the command `sudo systemctl start apache2.service`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to start apache, you need to run one of the following commands:

```
sudo apache2ctl start
sudo service apache2 start
sudo systemctl start apache2
```

Those commands will load environment variables. Running `apache2` by itself will not work as you will be missing needed steps to run apache.

Comment: I've used the first code and it showed me this AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
httpd (pid 1460) already running

Comment: @Matei The fist part is just a warning; check the following Q/A for a fix: http://askubuntu.com/questions/256013/apache-error-could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-n. While the last part `httpd (pid 1460) already running`is saying that Apache is already started.