# Apache2 restart issues after editing virtualhost

Tags: server, apache2

hello i try to restart apache2 with command s`ervice apache2 restart` and it's give me this :

```
Restarting web server apache2                                                AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. 
Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

"" Please i need help whit thsi !!!!!

Comment: That's just a warning, not an error.  Apache2 should be running, here is similar.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/256013/apache-error-could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-n

Answer (score 1):

You need to *"Set the ['ServerName'](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servername) directive globally to suppress this [warning] message"*. For this purpose edit `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and place somewhere inside the directive:

```
ServerName localhost
```

Or instead `localhost` you can use some other host name defined in `/etc/hosts`, or a [domain name](https://serverfault.com/a/269840/364207) which is [connected](https://askubuntu.com/q/900523/566421) to your server if there is one.

---

In this context, the term *Globally* or *Server config* level, as it is [described](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directive-dict.html#Context) on Apache's website, "means that the directive may be used in the server configuration files (e.g., `httpd.conf` or `apache2.conf`), but not within any `<VirtualHost>` or `<Directory>` containers. It is not allowed in `.htaccess` files at all."