# Configuring Request Tracker 5.0.2 with Apache2 on Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS; Release:18.04;

Tags: server, apache2, webserver

I am trying to install Request Tracker 5.0.2 with Apache2 on VM with config.— Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS; Release:18.04; and followed the following tutorial to install RT5 https://rt-wiki.bestpractical.com/wiki/ManualInstallation.

So I used the readme from https://docs.bestpractical.com/rt/5.0.2/web_deployment.html for web configuration.
When I try to restart the Apache and I try to get my webpage it sends me this
message:

```
You’re almost there!
You haven't yet configured your webserver to run RT. 
You appear to have installed RT's web interface correctly, but haven't yet configured your webserver to "run" the RT server which powers the web interface. 

The next step is to edit your webserver's configuration file to instruct it to use RT's mod_perl or FastCGI handler. If you need commercial support, please contact us at sales@bestpractical.com.
```

I haven’t found what else I must change in Apache’s configuration file.

Here is the code I have in rt.conf:

```
<VirtualHost rt.example.com(No worries here)>

        AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot "/opt/rt5/share/html"

        <Location />
            Require all granted
            Options +ExecCGI
            AddHandler fcgid-script fcgi
        </Location>

       <Perl>
            use Plack::Handler::Apache2;
            Plack::Handler::Apache2->preload("/opt/rt5/sbin/rt-server");
       </Perl>

        LogLevel debug ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I tried to work around by following different instructions in this guide and others but still face the same issue:https://hendgrow.com/2020/09/25/how-to-install-rt-5-robust-high-volume-ticketing-system-ubuntu-20-04-with-mariadb-and-apache2/

If any more information is needed, please let me know. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: @matigo With ScriptAlias / /opt/rt5/sbin/rt-server.fcgi/
I got this issue:
Internal Server Error: The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration.  tried to stop apache2 and restart: apachectl stop
but got following error: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
found suggestion: https://askubuntu.com/questions/256013/apache-error-could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-n   updated the server name; the issue repeated

Comment: Also, this line in the above code is shown as an issue: "use Plack::Handler::Apache2;" so I commented the whole <perl> ... </ perl> part but I cannot find another way to edit the webserver's configuration file to instruct it to use RT's mod_perl or FastCGI handler as this is the method suggested in the documentation.

Comment: The `ServerName` thingie isn't particularly important usually. If you're seeing an HTTP 500 (Internal Server) error, then there should be something more specific and actionable in the `/var/log/apache2/error.log` file letting you know exactly what the problem is, such as a missing file or directory.

Comment: @matigo Thank you! Yes, this is what I found in the error log as the core issue but I cannot find much information around:  Since your configuration exists (/opt/rt5/etc/RT_SiteConfig.pm) but is not writable, I'm refusing to do anything. 

[fcgid:warn] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server 
[core:error] End of script output before headers: rt-server.fcgi
I really appreciate your feedback!

Comment: If you run `sudo service apache2 reload` (*not* `restart`), does the system start up properly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132556/discussion-between-nil-and-matigo).

Comment: Same issue: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server