# session closed for user pi when restarting apache2 server

Tags: apache2, reboot

When restarting the apache server with this command `sudo service apache2 restart` I get an error

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.


journalctl | tail
Apr 02 11:43:34 raspberrypi sudo[11952]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user pi
Apr 02 11:43:46 raspberrypi sudo[11965]:     root : PWD=/usr/share/piwiz ; USER=pi ; ENV=XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000 ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/
Apr 02 11:43:46 raspberrypi sudo[11965]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user pi(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Apr 02 11:43:49 raspberrypi sudo[11965]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user pi
Apr 02 11:44:01 raspberrypi sudo[11979]:     root : PWD=/usr/share/piwiz ; USER=pi ; ENV=XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000 ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/
Apr 02 11:44:01 raspberrypi sudo[11979]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user pi(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Apr 02 11:44:04 raspberrypi sudo[11979]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user pi
Apr 02 11:44:16 raspberrypi sudo[11992]:     root : PWD=/usr/share/piwiz ; USER=pi ; ENV=XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000 ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/
Apr 02 11:44:16 raspberrypi sudo[11992]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user pi(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Apr 02 11:44:19 raspberrypi sudo[11992]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user pi



systemctl status apache2.service
apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2022-04-02 11:42:38 CEST; 5min ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 11891 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 87ms

Apr 02 11:42:38 raspberrypi apachectl[11894]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, usi>
Apr 02 11:42:38 raspberrypi apachectl[11894]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
Apr 02 11:42:38 raspberrypi apachectl[11894]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
Apr 02 11:42:38 raspberrypi apachectl[11894]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Apr 02 11:42:38 raspberrypi apachectl[11894]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Apr 02 11:42:38 raspberrypi apachectl[11891]: Action 'start' failed.
Apr 02 11:42:38 raspberrypi apachectl[11891]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Apr 02 11:42:38 raspberrypi systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 02 11:42:38 raspberrypi systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 02 11:42:38 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Comment: Hello. A good place to start any question is what version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: You will also want to check `/var/log/apache2/error.log` for more specific details regarding any issue 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache error "Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256013/apache-error-could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-n)